# Trouble with controlling a ScrollView from a Popover

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm a junior and I have been really struggling to get this to work, would really appreciate some help.

I am trying to build an App where you can scroll through different WebViews by selecting an item from a table in a popover (while the popover remains in place).  Unfortunately, I can't get my scrollView to move when I select an item from the popover view.

I have set up a UIScrollView with page control in a main UIViewController. The scrollView is populated with (pageViewController) UIWebViews. The main UIViewController has a nav bar with a button, when the button is clicked it creates a Popover View. When I select an item from the table in the popover view I want my UIScrollView to scroll to a certain position (equates to a selected page), but the scrollView does not move.

The method below takes the value selected from the popover and uses the page number to determine where the scrollView should scroll to, but it doesn't work because at this point my scrollView is Null.
I can supply more code if needed.

main UIViewController.m code:

```
    - (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {


    if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [detailItem release];
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];


        NSString *pgnum = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[detailItem description]];
        int pg;

        if(pgnum == @"Page 1"){
            pg =1;

        }

        if(pgnum == @"Page 2"){

            pg =2;
        }

        if(pgnum == @"Page 3"){
           pg =3;
        }

        [pgnum release];

        pageControl.currentPage = pg;
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:pg - 1];
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:pg];
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:pg + 1];
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pg;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
        pageControlUsed = YES;

    }

    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }   


}
```

This is how I triggered the popOverController
The infoButton is on the navbar.
The scrollView is NOT NULL in the infoButton

```
- (void)infoButton:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Entering: infoButton");

   // [self inspectView:self.view level:@""];

if (self.popoverController == nil) {
 PopoverViewController *popoverViewController = 
 [[PopoverViewController alloc]      
 initWithNibName:@"PopoverViewController" 
 bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

 popoverViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Navigation";
 UINavigationController *navController = 
 [[UINavigationController alloc] 
 initWithRootViewController:popoverViewController];

 UIPopoverController *popover = 
 [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
 initWithContentViewController:navController]; 

 popover.delegate = self;
 [popoverViewController release];
 [navController release];

 self.popoverController = popover;
 [popover release];

 //NSLog(@"User pressed the info button");
 }

 [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIPopover`, being neither the most obvious class to use memory-management wise, nor the most stable, does not require you to release it before you present it.  In fact, doing so causes it to throw a fatal exception!  Popovers should be released after they are removed from the screen, and/or in `-dealloc`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have removed the [popover release], but this didn't seem to fix the problem.  My problem is the scrollView doesn't scroll to a horizontal position after having selected a page number from the popover (the scrollView shows null in the debugger).

Comment: You may not even be instantiating a scrollView then, or like the popover you may heave released it before you starting calling on it to scroll.  Use the -contentOffset property of the scrollview to set it, and go back through your methods to check for [[scrollview alloc] init...] and [scrollview release];

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I removed all the releases, but I still had the same problem.  So instead I tried a different tack. I have removed the table from the popover and replaced with buttons.  This worked.  The scrollView moves to the location associated with the button.  I guess the table and its scroller some how caused the problem. Thanks again for your support with this.

Comment: No problem, best of luck with this.